# Why my iOS simulator can't be put on AZERTY mode

Tags: ios, internationalization, keyboard

I'm trying painfully to change my simulator on AZERTY, but it won't. Always stuck on QWERTY, and i can't find why.

From the simulator I have changed my keyboard preference on AZERTY, and on internationalisation the French country. But when I launch my apps, it is always stuck on QWERTY. What is strange is that when I choose hardware->keyboard->connect hardware Keyboard and hardware->keyboard->IOS use same layout as Mac OSX, it is still stuck on qwerty.

Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xcode 6.1, this is a known bug:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html

> Localization and Keyboard settings, including 3rd party keyboards, are not correctly honored by Safari, Maps, and developer apps in the iOS 8.1 Simulator. [NSLocale currentLocale] returns en_US and only the English and Emoji keyboards are available. (18418630, 18512161)